# Typesafe heterogeneous container

Tags: java

I was reading Joshua Blochs "Effective Java 2nd edition" item 29, which describes how to create Heterogeneous containers, in the end of chapter he wrote:

> A Class object used in this fashion is called a type token. You can
>   also use a custom key type. For example, you could have a DatabaseRow
>   type representing a database row (the container), and a generic type
>   Column as its key.

It wondered me and I wrote this implementation which he has mentioned. Is there something I could have done better ? I'm mostly interested in `Column` class which serves as `Type Token`

```
class Column<T> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T cast(Object obj) {
        return (T) obj;
    }
}

public class DatabaseRow {

    private Map<Column<?>, Object> row = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> void putColumn(Column<T> type, T instance) {
        row.put(type, type.cast(instance));
    }

    public <T> T getColumn(Column<T> type) {
        return type.cast(row.get(type));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DatabaseRow db = new DatabaseRow();

        Column<Integer> colInt = new Column<>();
        Column<Double> colDouble = new Column<>();

        db.putColumn(colInt, 1);
        db.putColumn(colDouble, 10.0);

        System.out.println(colInt.getClass() + " " + colDouble.getClass());
        System.out.println(db.getColumn(colInt) + " " + db.getColumn(colDouble));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things I would like to point out here.

1. There is no need to do the cast on the `putColumn` call. The method signature is: `public <T> void putColumn(Column<T> type, T instance) {` so we know that instance is of type `T` already, and it is being stored in an `Object` value in a Map. There is no reason to force the cast before storing it.
2. The Column's cast method would be better done using a `Class<T>` instance. Consider the 'standard' pattern of requiring a class instance in the constructor of the Column. For example:

   ```
   class Column<T> {

       private final Class<T> valClass;
       public Column(Class<T> valClass) {
           this.valClass = valClass;
       }

       public T cast(Object obj) {
           return obj == null ? null : valClass.cast(obj);
       }
   }
   ```

   this has the benefit of not requiring the SuppressWarnings. It also ends up being helpful for other reasons too.

   The class would be used as:

   ```
   Column<String> col = new Column(String.class);
   ```

   Apart from that, things will be the same.

Comment: http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~mmh/APD/bloch/generics.pdf

I think you would need to correct your point no1 . cast in the put is required to achieve typesafety with a dynamic cast